# How to let jMeter http request sampler generate parameters?

Tags: parameters, query-string, jmeter

Is there a way to generate random parameter values in jMeter http request sampler or any other sampler?

Comment: Not sure about that but you could generate your random values some other ways and put them into a csv file and use (CSV Data Set Config) in jmeter to load your data.

Comment: I use this idea now, but it's not very convenient. I was hoping that there is a way to make it out of the box.
anyway thanks for an answer.

Comment: I think Alies Belik provided a solution to your question, however most of the time I'ld go with Razh's reply, as it's more desirable resource consumption wise.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In JMeter, you can use `counters` to generate parameter values. Add your `counter` to the top of your test plan and choose `initial`, `increment` and `maximum` values. It will start counting automatically.

`counter` is in `Pre Processors` menu. You can use the counter values in HTTP samplers by using `reference name`. i.e. let's say your reference name is **`ref_counter`** then you can call its values in HTTP samplers with **`${ref_counter}`**.

Comment: thanks, with counter config element I found random config element, that was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Rasalom, Just for correctness you should accept Alies Belik answer and upvote Kerim Karaca as it helped you. Because the aim of SO is to find the right answer

Answer (score 22):

You can try to use some of [jmeter's functions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) to generate random value:

- [__Random](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) to generate random int: `${__Random(MIN, MAX}`;
- [__RandomString](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) to generate random string: `${__RandomString(LENGTH)}`;

as well as [Random Variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Variable) config element for the same purpose.